# Program behaving differently when started from shell vs PHP's exec()

Tags: php

I seem to have a program [casperjs][1] running properly when typing its command in the shell,

```
casperjs hello.js
```

but not when you use `php's exec()`:

```
exec('casperjs hello.js');
```

jQuery does not seem to be injected.

Is it possible that there are more `putenv()` that needs to be defined?

**Attempt:** I logged in as the nginx user `su www-data` and ran the command from shell again and it works fine.

Comment: While `su` lets you run programs as another user, I don't think it imports their environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider that PHP may not necessarily import the same environment variables that you would have in your profile when running this program from your shell. PHP only imports the environment variables inherited by the shell or CGI program that the interpreter is running under. So when you run `exec` functions from PHP that's usually whatever your default shell is configured to on that system. Once a shell starts up it will normally import whatever the user `.profile` defines in their home directory. For PHP this includes whatever the interpreter is running under (so in Apache for example you can use `SetEnv VAR VALUE` in *.htaccess* or *httpd.conf* to set those environment variables up for PHP). From the command line you'll have to export those variables you need with `putenv` and you can see them in the `$_ENV` superglobal.

You'll have to figure out for yourself from whatever program you're using and its documentation what environment variables it requires to run properly. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with what you're using or its requirements. PHP also has no control over what environment variables external programs depend on to run. But you can see your users' environment from the shell by typing `env` from the command line and you get all of your existing ENVIRONMENT variables and their values.